# Laravel (5.4) link to a css file

Tags: css, laravel, url, styles, assets

I'm trying to link a css file into this blade `header.blade.php`
It doesn't work, and nothing I've tried so far would work, except if i put the  into the same file of the `*.blade.php` that I'm using.

**:::layouts/header.blade.php:::**

```
@section('header')
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Help</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>

 </head>
<body>

@stop
////eof////
```

**:::master.blade.php:::**

```
@extends('layouts/header')
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    @if (Route::has('login'))
        <div class="top-right links">
           @auth
               <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
                    <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                @endauth
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Master
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Work</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@yield('footer')
```

Comment: Care to post exactly _what_ you have tried?

Comment: Where is the css file located?

Comment: You're using the `asset` helper only for your JavaScript. It should be used for all assets, stylesheets included.

Comment: It'd be helpful to the community if you actually posted your code on your question, rather than deliberately adding spaces to an external link to circumvent the community rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other question.. to append to the current answer:

I've noticed that using @extends appends the HTML instead of inserting at the point where the function is called.

How to prevent this and so the html from the calling file goes where it's supposed to go (at the function call)?

**SOLUTION**

use @include instead

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your css file is in your 'public' directory, ie: 'public/css/styles.css'

Then try:

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ url('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this code in your header.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/styles.css') !!}" media="all" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the asset or url link
it was @section('header') and @stop in the first file -- **layouts/header.blade.php**.

Because using extend doesn't yield the content, yet it extends the html page -- I must've removed those from the html (or php) file (that is).

Best regards.